# 80's Scifi Show with Egyptian looking flying robots

Tags: story-identification, tv, robots

Does anyone remember an 80's or early 90's TV show with Egyptian looking flying robots in it? It was on the Super Channel in the UK. It was primitive looking CGI in the computer game style of the time?

Not Star Gate :)

Can't remember what it was called?

Also there was some gold reference in it... I think there was a gold thrust :)

Comment: @Otis if accepted, yes. The consensus on meta (can't find the relevant meta question as I'm on mobile) is that ID requests are only duplicates if they have the same, (possibly informally) accepted answer.

Comment: @SQB is correct. [Here's](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7065/closing-story-ident-questions-as-duplicates-where-theres-no-acceptance) the link to meta consensus.

Comment: @SQB, I understand. Just laying the trail for future action, as well as to benefit future searchers via the "linked" section at right.

Answer (score 9):

This would be *[Captain Power and the Soldiers of the Future](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captain_Power_and_the_Soldiers_of_the_Future)*, where some of the bad guys indeed looked like Egyptian robots. They were called [Bio-Dreads](https://soldiersofthefuture.fandom.com/wiki/Bio-Dread).

I remember watching it on either Sky Channel or Super Channel.

[image: An "Egyptian robot": a large lilac computer-generated robot with a bird-like beak, Bat-mannish wings, pink eyes, raising a gun]

---

*Confirmed by the querant in a comment:*

> Thank you.. that's it :) Loved it and it was Super Channel.. [—Arvo](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/128793/80s-scifi-show-with-egyptian-looking-flying-robots/128795#comment325307_128795)

Comment: Written by [J. Michael Straczinski](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0833089/), of [Babylon 5](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/babylon-5) fame.

Comment: Thank you.. that's it :) Loved it and it was Super Channel..

Comment: @Arvo Don't forget to accept the answer as correct by clicking the checkmark on the left :-)

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure it was from the 80s, or could it be [Johnny Sokko and his Flying Robot](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0170962/?ref_=ttmd_md_nm)?

From the [IMDb reviews](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0170962/reviews) (emphasis mine):

> Watching **a Egyptian mummy faced robot** fighting monsters was a dream for me as well as for every other kid I knew. I remember how hard I cried when the giant robot lost his eyes and also during the episode where he was beaten badly, I envied Johnny so much. **Today I know the special effects are much much better** and there are a plethora of new sci- fi based programs but they cant even hold a torch to good ol' Johnny and his robot.

And:

> Obviously, the series is the American redubbing of the Japanese series Giant Robo (or Jianto Robo). The names have been changed, though the premise is largely intact. The alien Emperor Guillotine seeks to conquer the Earth, through his criminal organization of thugs and monsters; and, what an organization it is! The Gargoyle Gang consists of beatnick Che Guevara/Nazi soldiers (with stylish wraparound sunglasses), a silver headed alien lieutenant with shelf- like eyebrow ridges (Dr. Botanus); a buck toothed, giant foreheaded, one legged lieutenant (Fangar); a one eyed playing card obsessive (Harlequin), and **a nutjob in golden knight's armor (Goldennock)**. meanwhile, their leader is a cross-eyed alien, with tentacles hanging from his head. This bunch of misfits, along with their various monsters and weaponry, seek to subjugate the planet, for whatever reason. Opposing them is Unicorn a security organization that thinks it's OK for a little boy (and, later, a little girl) to casually be exposed to danger and carry a gun. To be fair, the kid seems to be the only one with any sense in the organization. They also seem to adopt stereotypical dress in their subsidiaries around the globe (tyrolean hats, turbans, etc...). The group usually needs the Giant Robot to get them out of a jam, though they do occasionally rescue the kid, so he can call in the robot.

Comment: I'm going to re watch it and check out Giant Robo.. Thanks..